# Webpack - Separate CSS/JS bundles for administration dashboard

Tags: webpack

My current configuration bundles Javascript and CSS separately. But, I have specific styles and JS that are only relevant to the administration dashboard on my site and I do not want them to be included in the `styles.css` stylesheet.

Is it possible to do this?

Here's my current Webpack configuration:

```
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './lib/js/entry.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
                    loader: [
                        'css-loader?importLoaders=1',
                        'postcss-loader'
                    ]
                })
            },
            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [code splitting guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/). Possible solutions are [multiple entries](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/#multiple-entries), or using the [`CommonsChunkPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/#commonschunkplugin).